# Problema para fazer logon usando PHP e CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, login

Peguei um sistema interno da empresa para dar manutenção e não tenho muito conhecimento em `PHP`. Quando faço logon na aplicação estando no servidor da empresa consigo acessar normalmente. Subi a aplicação em uma hospedagem, porém, ao tentar fazer logon inserindo email e senha, o que aparece é uma tela em branco, e não consigo fazer logon.

Segue o código para análise:

**View 'login/entrar':**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="<?= site_url ("Login/entrar") ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="GFSc0XajfwJeVrp2CzYdftCoZ8tslaOkBfIIbLdc">
    <div class="form-group">                      
        <label for="login" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="login" value="" required autofocus>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="senha" class="col-md-4 control-label">Senha</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="senha" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">                                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                Entrar
            </button>
            <!--a class="btn btn-link" href="http://192.168.31.8/vistarraf/password/reset" disabled=disabled>
                Esqueceu sua senha?
            </a -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller 'login':**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller{

    public function index(){}

    public function entrar (){
        $login = $this->input->post("login");
        $senha = md5($this->input->post("senha"));
        $this->db->where("email", $login);
        $this->db->where("password", $senha);
        $query = $this->db->get("users");
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1){
            $this->load->helper('weather_helper');
            $previsao = MostraPrevisao(4956);
            $dados    = array(
                'titulo'    => 'Intranet',
                'tela'      => 'inicio',
                'previsao'  => $previsao
            );
            $this->load->view('home_view', $dados);
        } 
        else {
            $mensagem = "Email e Senha não encontrados"; 
            $dados    = array(
                'msg' => $mensagem,
                'tela'      => 'welcome_message_error'                
            );
            $this->load->view('login_view', $dados);      
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Precisa verificar o tipo de erro que está sendo retornado.

Comment: Matheus, olá! Dê uma olhadinha se está configurado corretamente a base URL no arquivo /applications/config/config.php.

Comment: como posso verificar o tipo de erro que está retornando?

Comment: @CesarAugusto, a base URL está configurada.

Comment: De qualquer maneira era pro método chamar `$this->load->view('login_view', $dados);`, afinal, qualquer coisa diferente de `$query->num_rows() == 1` era pra cair na exceção, mas por algum motivo ele não está chamando a exceção, o que me faz pensar que é algo na configuração do servidor ou alguma `view` faltando, ou coisa do gênero.